# Searching by input in an array of objects(useState) and getting the value of objects in React.js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

The first time I write a name and press search, a name is added to the nameSurname array that appears on the screen, the second time I write a surname, and this is also added. When the job button is clicked, I have to check if there is a person with this first and last name in the user array, then display his job with the p tag at the bottom of the job button.

[image]

```
function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState([
    { name : "Matthew", surname : 'Barr', job: 'Software consultant'},
    { name : "Janice",surname : 'Brownlee', job: 'Tattooist' },
    { name : "John", surname : 'Bryan', job: 'Economist' },
    { name : "Matthew",surname : 'Cringle', job: 'Sportsperson' },
 ])
  const [nameSurname, setNameSurname] = useState([])
  const {register, handleSubmit, formState: {errors}, reset} = useForm()
  
  const save = (a) => {
    setNameSurname([...nameSurname, a]);
    reset()
  }

  const writeJob = () => {
    if(user.filter((a) => a.name.includes(nameSurname))) {
      
    }
  }

  return <>
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(save)}>
      <input type="text" placeholder='search' className='form-control w-25 m-3' {...register('search', {required: true})}/>
      {errors.search && <p>Error</p>}
      <button className='btn btn-primary m-3'>Search</button>
    </form>
    <hr />
    <div>
      {
        nameSurname.map((el, i) => {
          return <p key={i} className='m-2 text-danger'>{el.search}</p>
        })
      }
      <button className='btn btn-info m-3' onClick={() => writeJob()}>Job</button>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </>
}
```

Comment: Does the app have to follow the logic of using a single input to enter name and then surname? Would you be able to type name and surname together at the same time? I feel like there are easier ways to go about what you're trying to implement.

Comment: @Andrey, You are forgetting to mention. About what kind of and what error you are facing with your code. Please consider the to add error or problem in your question.

Comment: If you want To check if a person with a given first and last name exists in the user array, you can use the `Array.prototype.find()` or `find` method.

Comment: Here is with `find` `const person = user.find(person => person.firstName === firstName && person.lastName === lastName);`

Comment: First name and then last name in one input, can do it one by one,
 const person = user.find(person => person.firstName == nameSurname[0] && person.lastName == nameSurname[0]);
Иesides this method, you can somehow take the first name then surname

Comment: @RyanZeelie Means, for example, with two inputs?

Comment: @Andrey well personally I would still use one but limit it to a single search. So typing in Matthew and hitting search would bring up all entries containing Matthew with a job button next to each so the user can click on which one they want. But this conversation about design could go on forever..

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should create a variable for example `userResult` to store the user that match the search values.

As you are saying that you are searching depending on the name and surname so you have to update your filter conditions so you can compare the first value in `nameSurname` array with the name of the user and the second value of the array with the surname of the user, your filter function should look like this :`user.filter((a) => a.name.includes(nameSurname[0]) && a.surname.includes(nameSurname[1]))`

then in your `writeJob` function you search in the users array using the `.filter()` function, it will return an array of results, you should test if the array is not empty, then you get the first value of the array which is the result that match your search result and store it in your `userResult` variable, else if there are no result you set the `userResult` as null that will help in the conditional rendering that we will use to show the job

last step is to make the conditional rendering using the operator `&&` in the return function to show the job if there is a result of the search, we acheive that like this : `{userResult && <p>{userResult.job}</p>}`

So your code must look something like:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState([
  { name: "Matthew", surname: 'Barr', job: 'Software consultant' },
  { name: "Janice", surname: 'Brownlee', job: 'Tattooist' },
  { name: "John", surname: 'Bryan', job: 'Economist' },
  { name: "Matthew", surname: 'Cringle', job: 'Sportsperson' },
])
const [nameSurname, setNameSurname] = useState([])
const [userResult, setUserResult] = useState(null)
const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors }, reset } = useForm()

const save = (a) => {
  setNameSurname([...nameSurname, a]);
  reset()
}

const writeJob = () => {
  const userSearchResult = user.filter((a) => a.name.includes(nameSurname[0]) && a.surname.includes(nameSurname[1]));
  if (userSearchResult.length > 0) {
    setUserResult(userSearchResult[0])
  } else {
    setUserResult(null)
  }
}

return <>
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(save)}>
    <input type="text" placeholder='search' className='form-control w-25 m-3' {...register('search', { required: true })} />
    {errors.search && <p>Error</p>}
    <button className='btn btn-primary m-3'>Search</button>
  </form>
  <hr />
  <div>
    {
      nameSurname.map((el, i) => {
        return <p key={i} className='m-2 text-danger'>{el.search}</p>
      })
    }
    <button className='btn btn-info m-3' onClick={() => writeJob()}>Job</button>
    {userResult && <p>{userResult.job}</p>}
  </div>
</>
```

Comment: It's important to not just post code, but to also include a description of what the code does and why you are suggesting it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the code, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question or answer, @Haroun Darjaj.

Comment: @DSDmark Thanks for your remark that I took in consideration and I updated my answer to add detailed explanation of what I did, I hope that you will change your downVote it will be appreciated

Comment: @Andrey I added extra detailes to clear the idea of my answer I hope that will help you and if so I wish you will choose my answer as the best one , thanks

Comment: @HarounDarjaj  Job button doesn't work when clicked

Comment: @Andrey did you try values for name and username similar to the ones defined in your data?

Comment: @HarounDarjaj yes, console.log(userResult) always null